# Is there a guide regarding places least known/visited in Japan?

Tags: online-resources, japan, guidebooks

While I can find guides regarding places to visit in Japan, they all seem to promote the same places Tokyo shopping, inner city shrines, etc. Is there a website or book regarding places in Japan that promote the lesser known parts of Japan?

Comment: The least known places have no guide... as soon as a guide is written, they're no longer least-known.

Comment: Even some places that are listed in Lonely Planet aren't heavily visited. I went to the Ikebukuro Earthquake Museum, which was listed there, and the staff were surprised at someone who was obviously a foreign tourist visiting the museum. I explained that my Mum studied geology, and that I'm a scientist, and that explained it for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's the name of those four nucleur reactors that were leaking fuel last year???? - only joking. How about here => http://wikitravel.org/en/Off_the_beaten_track_in_Japan

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, and the response will not be able to help the person who posted it. However, these questions and answers do help others who may be searching for such answers. Considering this, here is one such guide for [tourist places in Japan](https://www.ejable.com/japan-corner/travel-in-japan/japan-lesser-known-best-tourist-places/) that are comparatively less known.

And believe me, such places generally give much better experiences than the hot tourist spots.

The site I linked to is my own.